# Increasing/decreasing input by a decimal value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's html:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus"/>
        <input id="qty1" type="text" value="1" class="qty"/>
        <img id="add1" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20" class="add"/>
    </p>

</body>
```

Here's js:

```
$(function () {
    $('.add').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseFloat($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 0.1);
        }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseFloat($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 0.1);
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hMS6Y/30/

When i try to increase or decrease input value by 0.1 i am getting some strange values like:

1.1 is ok
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003

how can i make them look: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and so on.

Comment: https://wiki.theory.org/YourLanguageSucks#Type_System JavaScript is *not* a programming language with high precision. You believe 0.1 plus 0.2 is 0.3? Wrong! JavaScript: `0.1+0.2 == 0.3 //false`

Comment: @Jack That post may answer why the OP is getting the results, but does not answer his question about how to format the values to display as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using like this

```
            $(function () {
        $('.add').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
            var currentVal = parseFloat($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $qty.val(parseFloat(currentVal + 0.1).toFixed(1));
            }
        });
        $('.minus').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
            var currentVal = parseFloat($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                $qty.val(parseFloat(currentVal - 0.1).toFixed(1));
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: toFixed(1) did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

You can use - `.toFixed(1)` to round it up to the decimal place you desire:

Here you go: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMS6Y/36/)

```
$(function () {
$('.add').on('click',function(){
    var qty = $(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
    var currentVal = parseFloat($(qty).val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $(qty).val((currentVal + 0.1).toFixed(1));
    }
});
$('.minus').on('click',function(){
    var qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
    var currentVal = parseFloat($(qty).val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $(qty).val((currentVal - 0.1).toFixed(1));
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One accepted workaround is to translate the expression to integer math, then convert back afterwards, i.e.

// add case

```
$qty.val((currentVal*10 + 1)/10);
```

// subtract case

```
$qty.val((currentVal*10 - 1)/10);
```

Comment: There is no integer type in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It is common in Javascript to have unexpected behaviors, but this one is particulary vicious.

10000000000000000 === 10000000000000001

Javascript doesn’t have integer type but lets you think it has. parseInt and parseFloat built-in functions, the fact that “1″ is displayed as “1″ and not as “1.0″ (like many languages) contribute to the general misunderstood.

[Source](http://greweb.me/2013/01/be-careful-with-js-numbers/)

---

You can use 
[Javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum).